# Android dialog with single choice list with array of names and specifield ID

Tags: android, arraylist, dialog, fragment

I want to create a dialog with single choice list but filled 
over the internet and I must use specific id for names, like my preferencefragment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                        jsonobject2 = (JSONObject) list.get(i);

                        entryValues2.add(jsonobject2.getString(TAG_ID));
                        entries2.add(jsonobject2.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("city");
                        listPreference.setEntries(entries2
                                .toArray(new String[entries2.size()]));
                        listPreference.setEntryValues(entryValues2
                                .toArray(new String[entryValues2.size()]));
```

I want to show only entries in dialog without id, but every "city" has an id which is used by another class and I must save only the id.

Answer (score 0):

try saving the (id,cityName) in a `HashMap`/`ArrayList` or using any storage methord available
1. `HashMap<int, String> city = new HashMap<int, String>();`
2. save in internal storage [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
3. save in Database using [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: Can I get a code may be?Coz I don't understand, or may be I mean aside. I want to put specifield id and name to a list. Showing only the name and saving just the id. But I dont know how to put to list these two things because everywhere I find only '.setSingleChoiceItems( R.array.Continent, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener())' and that means only one string or int array.